# Many-to-Many relationship flattening using AutoMapper

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper-9

I am using EF Core and I have many-to-many relationship between two tables.

```
 public class Sale
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public double Total { get; set; }
        public List<SalePaymentMethod> SalePaymentMethods { get; set; }
    }
```

Join Table :

```
    public class SalePaymentMethod
{
    public int DefferedPaymentCount { get; set; }
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public Sale Sale { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public int PaymentMethodId { get; set; }
    public PaymentMethod PaymentMethod { get; set; }
}
```

The other table of the relation:

```
public class PaymentMethod
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PaymentName { get; set; }
    public bool PaymentType { get; set; }
    public List<SalePaymentMethod> SalePaymentMethods { get; set; }

}
```

Can I get a flattened object as the following using AutoMapper?

```
public class SaleUserBranchProductsDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
    public List<PaymentMethodDto> PaymentMethods { get; set; }
}
```

Where PaymentMethodDto is :

```
public class PaymentMethodDto
{
    public string PaymentName { get; set; }
    public bool PaymentType { get; set; }
    public int DefferedPaymentCount { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

My question may be that I want to do another mapping inside the main mapping.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @poke I waste my whole day trying to figure out how to solve it. A few minutes after posting this question I managed to solve it. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve it.

Create a profile to map`SalePaymentMethod` from to `PaymentMethodDto`

```
    public class PaymentMethodProfile : Profile
{
    public PaymentMethodProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SalePaymentMethod, PaymentMethodDto>()
             .ForMember(q => q.Amount, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Amount))
             .ForMember(q => q.DefferedPaymentCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.DefferedPaymentCount))
             .ForMember(q => q.PaymentName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PaymentMethod.PaymentName))
             .ForMember(q => q.PaymentType, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PaymentMethod.PaymentType));


    }
}
```

Create another profile to map form `Sale` to `SaleUserBranchProductsDTO`

```
public SaleUserBranchProductsProfile()
{
    CreateMap<Sale, SaleUserBranchProductsDTO>()
        .ForMember(q => q.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
        .ForMember(q => q.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Date))
        .ForMember(q => q.Total, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Total))
        //Here is the magic
        .ForMember(q=> q.PaymentMethoddtos, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.SalePaymentMethods));
}
```

}

Then use it like this :

```
 _mapper.ProjectTo<SaleUserBranchProductsDTO>(_context.Sales.Where(wh => wh.UserId == UserId)).ToList();
```